# Implement Mul and other operators where it is implemented on contained generic types

Tags: rust

I have a struct that I'm playing around with to make a `doc` field serializable alongside the associated variable:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Field<T> {
    val: T,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    doc: Option<String>,
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that you can do operations with `Field`s as though you were doing them on the contained `T`. Some examples of what I'm thinking, limited to `Mul`:

- `f64` multiplied by a `Field<T = f64>` outputs an `f64`
- `f64` multiplied by a `Field<T =` [`uom::si::Quantity`](https://docs.rs/uom/latest/uom/si/struct.Quantity.html)`>` outputs a `Quantity` (as `Mul` is implemented  for `f64` and `Quantity` already)
- etc. for any `T` and other operand type that already have a `Mul` implementation

I was able to get this far:

```rust
impl<A, B, C> Mul<B> for &Field<A> where A: Mul<B, Output = C> + Copy {
    type Output = C;
    
    fn mul(self, other: B) -> C {
        self.val * other
    }
}

// note this is for `f64` specifically, rather than a generic type
impl<B, C> Mul<&Field<B>> for f64 where f64: Mul<B, Output = C>, B: Copy {
    type Output = C;
    
    fn mul(self, other: &Field<B>) -> C {
        self * other.val
    }
}
```

Replacing the second `impl` with a more generic version:

```rust
// TODO: THIS IS BROKEN
impl<A, B, C> Mul<&Field<B>> for A where A: Mul<B, Output = C>, B: Copy {
    type Output = C;
    
    fn mul(self, other: &Field<B>) -> C {
        other.val * self
    }
}
```

Causes errors by recursion, as it wants `Mul` to be implemented for `&Field<&Field<&Field<...` etc. I'll never actually want a Field containing a Field, so if there is a way to disallow that (alas, negative trait bounds elude us), that would work. Or if there is a way to flatten a Field containing a Field, ignoring the `doc` field, that would be fine.

```rust
use core::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Field<T> {
    val: T,
}

impl<T> Field<T> {
    fn new(val: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            val
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Field::new(1.5);
    let b = Field::new(2.0);

    println!("field0 * field1 = {}", &a * &b);
    println!("4.0 * field1 = {}", 4.0 * &b);
    println!("field0 * 3.0 = {}", &a * 3.0);
}

impl<A, B, C> Mul<B> for &Field<A>
where
    A: Mul<B, Output = C> + Copy,
{
    type Output = C;

    fn mul(self, other: B) -> C {
        self.val * other
    }
}

// TODO: THIS IS BROKEN
impl<A, B, C> Mul<&Field<B>> for A
where
    A: Mul<B, Output = C>,
    B: Copy,
{
    type Output = C;

    fn mul(self, other: &Field<B>) -> C {
        other.val * self
    }
}

impl<B, C> Mul<&Field<B>> for f64
where
    f64: Mul<B, Output = C>,
    B: Copy,
{
    type Output = C;

    fn mul(self, other: &Field<B>) -> C {
        self * other.val
    }
}
```

[RUST PLAYGROUND LINK](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a4ac7c3c1509c2174da15f6c8864481)

Thanks!

Comment: even my brain doesn't compute what you want. I don't think you can do that.

Comment: You may be able to do what you want using [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#deref-coercion).

Comment: @Stargateur Your comment is unhelpful. It doesn't matter that 'even your brain' doesn't understand the question; the question and discussion aren't invalidated by that.

Answer (score 0):

Rust has problems with generic reverse operator implementations (i.e. `impl<A, B> Op<A> for MyStruct<B>` is fine, `impl<A, B> Op<MyStruct<B>> for A` will not compile). Even if you manage to circumvent the overflow error (which is not possible in current Rust), you will still have problems with coherence, shown if you remove the first impl which causes the overflow:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `A` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Field<B>`)
  --> src/lib.rs:56:6
   |
56 | impl<A, B, C> Mul<&Field<B>> for A
   |      ^ type parameter `A` must be covered by another type when it appears before the first local type (`Field<B>`)
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters appear before that first local type
   = note: in this case, 'before' refers to the following order: `impl<..> ForeignTrait<T1, ..., Tn> for T0`, where `T0` is the first and `Tn` is the last
```

What you want cannot be achieved in Rust.

On the other hand, you can make the non-reverse impls more general, by accepting both references and owned values:

```rust
impl<A, B> Mul<B> for Field<A>
where
    A: Mul<B>,
{
    type Output = <A as Mul<B>>::Output;

    fn mul(self, other: B) -> Self::Output {
        self.val * other
    }
}

impl<'a, A, B> Mul<B> for &'a Field<A>
where
    &'a A: Mul<B>,
{
    type Output = <&'a A as Mul<B>>::Output;

    fn mul(self, other: B) -> Self::Output {
        &self.val * other
    }
}
```